# Possibly sand in the pipes

Tags: plumbing

My Mom, 96 years old, lives in a 1978 Mobile home.

Her water just trickles into the house.  I have seen over the last two years
sand and at one point, orange hardpan in the water, (*it looked like orange soda*). Mom doesn't have any money, and with Covid-19 I'm strapped.

How can I blow out the sand from inside her house pipes outward.

I determined it is not coming from her personal well/pump, so it has to be a buildup in the pipes inside.  I need help big time, but when I called the drilling company that she used to install the pump, they told me they require $3,000 when the truck rolls in, $3000 when they start working, and another $3,000 when the truck rolls out. No way does Mom have that kind money, nor do I.

What can I do?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  You say that the just "trickles into the house" but you are suggesting that you want to "blow out the same from inside".  Is the sand INSIDE or OUTSIDE the house?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, we'll need more info before we have any chance of helping you. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: "*I determined it is not coming from her personal well/pump, so it has to be a buildup in the pipes inside*"  Sand build up in the pipe has to come from somewhere, it does not just build up on its own.  A drilling company is not the people to call unless you want a new well drilled. Have you asked a plumbing company for an estimate to look at blowing out the pipes ?

Comment: With galvanized pipes they corrode over time blocking water flow in extreme cases. Make sure your faucet aerators are not plugged up flush the pressure tank if it is a Dyphram style and flush the hot water heater. Beyond that find a handyman as that well guy is a rip-off. I have never seen sand plug pipes but faucet airators yes and corroded galvanized pipe yes.

Answer (score 0):

Remove some faucet aerator screen on the end of faucets (they unscrew) and see if the flow is stronger. These aerator/screens are where particles build up and cause reduced flow.

Answer (score 0):

Sand doesn't just settle in pipes unless a lot is coming in with the water . Likely it is hard water scale or steel pipes and they are rusted. Rust would explain "orange"water. Unfortunately no inexpensive fixes. Maybe a local plumber would at least know what the problem is. As answered ,cleaning or removing aerators from faucets may help.